# How do I change the ruby text language in Microsoft Word for Hanyu Pinyin?

Tags: simplified-characters, pinyin, input-methods

I would like to use the Phonetic Guide in Microsoft Word to learn Chinese by adding Hanyu Pinyin to Simplified and Traditional Chinese text.

However, when select a group of characters, the ruby text always comes out in Japanese. I used to have Japanese IME installed but have removed it. The Phonetic Guide used to display pinyin ruby text a year ago but mysteriously changed to Japanese. I have no idea what setting governs this.

Any idea how to change the ruby text to Pinyin? For instance, the image below is a snippet. It is showing the ruby text in Japanese even though Japanese IME has been removed.

[image]

Comment: Do you know whether you have both the Japanese language pack and the Chinese (Simplified) one installed? If both are, is the language of this particular text _set_ to _Chinese (Simplified, China)_ in MS Word, or is it something else?

Comment: I used to have Japanese language pack installed but uninstalled it. I only have Chinese (Simplified). English is the default language.

What is strange is that this used to output pinyin before. I haven't touched Japanese in several years, but now all of a sudden it always outputs Japanese even though I uninstalled Japanese IME.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about Microsoft product!

Comment: I brought it up on meta: [Is the question about changing ruby text in Microsoft Word off-topic?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1949/8099).  We need to flesh out these on/off-topic boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have installed the Chinese language pack for the office.

Select the texts first.

Then you can click either the top or the bottom language button to set the language of the texts.

[image]